I’ve noticed a form field for subscribing to a newsletter (email address) prohibits Apple’s Text Replacement in Safari. Can prohibition be removed?
This issue is something i’ve come across on many websites, the email address field won’t accept paste from the clipboard and it won’t allow Apple’s Text Replacement substitutions to activate inline. possibly a well intended limitation to slow down the bots.
example:
in Apple macOS or iphone or ipad OS you can set any glyph (text chars) combination as a trigger phrase to be replaced by some other collection of glyphs. i use extensively for things like “gwp20” →  “GWP₂₀” or “ch4” → “CH₄” but also for email addresses. eg “jb” → “jeffblogs@wordpress.org”
how would one go about tracing back the source of the code blocking email address form fields behaving like normal text fields with regard to pasting and text replacements? i believe the form might be a bit of Mailchimp code, either pasted or as some kind of a frame. i’m not the dev of this site, just a user tester/QA.
i réalise these special test entry preventions for email fields likely some kind of concern about bots spamming forms, but i am also aware that not all email fields on the web have these preventative controls.

WordPress has no built in newsletter forms, you'd need to share more information about the form in question but it's likely this isn't something that WordPress knowledge can help with if it's a 3rd party form embed. If it's Mailchimp code you're best asking their support about it

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
